# String formatting in C#

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, arguments, string-formatting

I'm working my way through a string formatting "cheat sheet", so that I can see how different string formatting arguments affect the string output. Whilst working with `DateTime` string formatting arguments, I wrote this little test:

```
char[] dtFormats = new char[] { 'd', 'D', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'm', 'o', 'r', 's', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'y' };
foreach (char format in dtFormats)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime format {0} = {1:" + format + "}", format, DateTime.Now);
}
```

All it does is show all the different formats for a `DateTime` using each argument.

That aside, I'd like to focus on this:

```
Console.WriteLine("DateTime format {0} = {1:" + format + "}", format, DateTime.Now);
```

Now I know that `{0}` is replaced with format *(argument 0)*, and `{1:?}` is replaced with `DateTime.Now` *(argument 1)*.

I tried to re-write this like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("DateTime format {0} = {1:{0}}", format, DateTime.Now);
```

This raises a `FormatException`, but I would like to know why you can't nest string place holders inside other format string place holders.

In this case it should replace `{0}` with the format argument, and `{1:{0}}` with `DateTime.Now`, followed by a colon and the format argument.

Is this not possible in C#?

EDIT:

For that matter, why does `Console.WriteLine("{{0}}", "Hello World");` result in `"{0}"` instead of `"{Hello World}"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about we simplify this a little? You're trying to nest braces when the syntax states that `{{` means a single literal `{`. This is what you're looking for:

```
Console.WriteLine("DateTime format {0} = {1}", format, DateTime.Now.ToString(format));
```

And to answer this question:

> For that matter, why does Console.WriteLine("{{0}}", "Hello World"); result in "{0}" instead of "{Hello World}"?

I reiterate that `{{`, syntactically means a single literal `{`.

Now, if you wanted to use the colon syntax, you have that wrong anyway, it works like this `{100:C}`, that would display `100` in a currency format. But you really don't need to do that here because getting that format to work would be difficult cause you need this `{1:{0}}` and that's going to fail because of the escape syntax.

Comment: It's a simple solution to this case (so +1), but it does not actually answer why you can't nest format place holders. Maybe I will have to write my own string formatting implementation...

Comment: @series0ne, I believe I may have been editing while you commented. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because a double curly `}}` escapes the curly braces in the formatted string.

As you've found, this:

```
string.Format("This {{is}} my {{escaped}} curlies");
```

..is fine (and results in `This {is} my {escaped} curlies)`.. because they are escaped. If you nest them like you have.. the parser won't know whether to escape or not.

Image being the parser and encountering this:

```
Console.WriteLine("DateTime format {0} = {1:{0}}", format, DateTime.Now);
/*                                            ^^ Okay, I'll escape this. WAIT!
                                                 .. now I have a two single
                                                 curly open braces. This is
                                                 a badly formatted format string
                                                 now.. FormatException!*/
```

Comment: Ah I see...Console.WriteLine("{{{0}}}", "Hello World"); produces "{Hello World}"

Comment: ...but unfortunately the same principle does not seem to work for the datetime formatting :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("DateTime format {0} = {{1:{0}}}", format), format, DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the format you cannot refer to any argument.

Answer (score 0):

A simple proceeding to make sure that you will not have any problem with characters being misundertood is separating what to put in each side: for the left side, just the references to the chunks with the minimum additional information possible; for the right side, as complex chunks as required (not just variables). Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("DateTime format {0}{1}{2}", format, " = {" + DateTime.Now, ":" + format + "}");
```

or even:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", "DateTime format " + format, " = {" + DateTime.Now, ":" + format + "}");
```

You might even rely on variables:

```
string chunk1 = "DateTime format " + format;
string chunk2 = " = {" + DateTime.Now;
string chunk3 = ":" + format + "}";
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", chunk1, chunk2, chunk3);
```